# How to set Window id in Mapbasic?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

Last couple of days i am working with creating thematic map using MapBasic. I am facing some difficulties while doing scripting and compilation.i am getting error due to Dynamic Window Id. does any code or solution to set window id? current window id i got while doing thematic map manually using mapinfo tools. if i used that window id in to my code it working, but only thing is that i have to open that window. if i closed that window and run my code with that window id it showing me incorrect window id.

anybody can tell me..how to solve this issue

thanks and regards

Comment: Your question has been answered on MapInfo-L.

Comment: thnks a lot...it help me lot....